# How to print values in javascript file from custom control

Tags: javascript, .net, controls

I am developing a Server Custom Control (a DatePicker), and i need to print values in the webResource (the javascript file).

I need two variables called "MinDate" and "MaxDate" filled in the Custom Control, and accesible from the web resource (the javascript file).

I couldn't find the answer, can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See if this can help http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/get-user-control-value-javascript-aspx-97186.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help, because it is an user control, and i am working with a custom control. I need to pass the values before the controls are rendered, because the javascript will set things about the control before it is displayed.